# Explain this different representation of object and class

Tags: java

Here in this `myClass` I could not understand the lines which are stared. Could anyone please explain how they work.

```
class myClass {
    private Vector locations;

    private void distances() {    
        Vector locn= locations;    
        if (locn!= null) {    
            for (int i = 0; i < locn.size(); i++) {
                ** Restaurant a = (Restaurant) locn.elementAt(i);
                ** a.setDistance(distanceToLocations(a));
            }
        }
    }

    private String distanceToLocations(Restaurant restaurant) {
        // returns string
    }
}
```

Here **`Restaurant` is a class** and **`setDistance()` is the method of class `Restaurant`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `elementAt` method of `Vector` is defined as returning `Object`, but apparently `locations` contains `Restaurant` entries. So in order to access the `Restaurant` methods, you have to *cast* the reference you get back from `Object` to `Restaurant`. That's what the `(Restaurant)` part of `(Restaurant)locn.elementAt(i);` is doing.

This is fairly old-fashioned code. The modern approach would be to use `Vector<Restaurant>` (or probably `List<Restaurant>` if you don't need synchronization) and the enhanced `for` loop:

```
class myClass
{
    private List<Restaurant> locations;    

    private void distances()    
    {    
        List<Restaurant> locn = locations; // You don't really need to do this bit
        if (locn!= null) {    
            for (Restaurant a : locn) {
                a.setDistance(distanceToLocations(a));
            }
        }
    }

    private String distanceToLocations(Restaurant restaurant) {
        // returns string
    }
}
```

Note I've changed `Vector` to `List`. You never show how `locations` is initialized, but with `List<Restaurant>` you'd do something like:

```
this.locations = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
// or
this.locations = new LinkedList<Restaurant>();
```

I'm guessing you don't really need synchronization. If you do, though, there are better options in `java.util` than `Vector`, such as using [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) to get a synchronized list, or using some of the things in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). And you'll need to synchronize during the loop. For instance:

```
this.locations = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Restaurant>());
```

and then

```
synchronized (locn) {
    for (Restaurant a : locn) {
        a.setDistance(distanceToLocations(a));
    }
}
```

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in Java code is to have class names start with an upper case character and use CamelCase, e.g. `MyClass` not `myClass`. `myClass` looks like a variable or field. You don't *have* to follow conventions, but doing so helps people read your code.

Comment: Note that if synchronization is needed, the code is flawed, since it iterates over the vector without synchronizing on it.

Answer (score 2):

The first one gets the restaurant stored at index i in the `locn` vector.

The second one calls the `distanceToLocations()` method, obtaing the result of this method, and calls `setDistance()` on the restaurant with this result as argument.

The code would be much easier to understand and type-safe if it respected Java naming conventions, used proper variable names, didn't use Vector (which should not be used anymore for more than 10 years), and used generic collections (`List<Restaurant>`) instead of raw types (`Vector`), which force you to use casts to tell the compiler: the object stored in the vector is in fact a Restaurant.

Comment: There is a generic Vector in JDK6.

Comment: Yes, Vector was made generic just like the other collections in Java 5. That's not the reason it shouldn't be used anymore. Vector shouldn't be used anymore since Java 1.2, when ArrayList was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

This is old-school code, here's a "modernized" version:

```
private void distances()    
{    
    if (this.locations != null) {    
        for (final Restaurant restaurant : this.locations) {
            restaurant.setDistance(distanceToLocations(restaurant));
        }
    }
}
```

This is more explicit - *I think*. The method iterates over `locations` (if not `null`) and for each `Restaurant` in it, `setDistance()` on the restaurant using `distanceToLocations` method.